# How to pass the where condition in nested query

Tags: sql

I am facing performance issue while running the following script. It is taking a lot of time to execute this query, more than 1 hour.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_TEST AS
SELECT UNID AS UNIT_ID,AG_ID,STATION,EID,NUM_1 AS EVENT_NUMBER,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(DP,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS DP,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(ER,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS ER,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(AR,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS AR,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TR,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS TR,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TA,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS TA,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TP,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS TP,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(PS,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS PS,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TG,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS TG,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(AG,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS AG,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(HB,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS HB,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TO_LOC,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS TO_LOC,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(AO,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS AO,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TC,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS TC,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(AC,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS AC,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(AM,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS AM,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(OS,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS OS,
TRIP_NO
FROM (
SELECT * FROM (SELECT u.UNID, u.AG_ID, u.STATION ,u.EID, u.NUM_1, u.CDTS,u.UNIT_STATUS,ATH_TRIP_NO(u.RECOVERY_CDTS,u.EID,u.NUM_1,u.UNID) TRIP_NO 
FROM UN_HI u 
WHERE u.RECOVERY_CDTS IN(SELECT MAX(RECOVERY_CDTS) AS RECOVERY_CDTS FROM UN_HI GROUP BY UNID,AG_ID,STATION,EID,UNIT_STATUS,ATH_TRIP_NO(RECOVERY_CDTS,EID,NUM_1,UNID)) 
) 
PIVOT (MIN(CDTS) FOR (UNIT_STATUS) IN ('DP' DP,'ER' ER, 'AR' AR,'TR' TR,'TA' TA,'TP' TP,'PS' PS,'TG' TG,'AG' AG,'HB' HB,'TO' TO_LOC,'AO' AO,'TC' TC,'AC' AC,'AM' AM,'OS' OS)) ) t1
GROUP BY UNID,AG_ID,STATION,EID,NUM_1,DP,ER,AR,TR,TA,TP,PS,TG,AG,HB,TO_LOC,AO,TC,AC,AM,OS,TRIP_NO
ORDER BY EID,UNID,TRIP_NO
```

When i run:

```
SELECT * FROM VW_TEST WHERE EID = 58100
```

Then it takes more than 1 hour.

But when i pass the where condition inside the nested query, the i get the result within 5 secs.

```
SELECT UNID AS UNIT_ID,AG_ID,STATION,EID,NUM_1 AS EVENT_NUMBER,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(DP,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS DP,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(ER,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS ER,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(AR,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS AR,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TR,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS TR,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TA,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS TA,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TP,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS TP,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(PS,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS PS,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TG,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS TG,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(AG,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS AG,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(HB,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS HB,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TO_LOC,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS TO_LOC,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(AO,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS AO,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TC,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS TC,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(AC,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS AC,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(AM,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS AM,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(OS,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS OS,
TRIP_NO
FROM (
SELECT * FROM (SELECT u.UNID, u.AG_ID, u.STATION ,u.EID, u.NUM_1, u.CDTS,u.UNIT_STATUS,ATH_TRIP_NO(u.RECOVERY_CDTS,u.EID,u.NUM_1,u.UNID) TRIP_NO 
FROM UN_HI u 
WHERE u.EID = 58100 AND u.RECOVERY_CDTS IN(SELECT MAX(RECOVERY_CDTS) AS RECOVERY_CDTS FROM UN_HI WHERE EID = 58100 GROUP BY UNID,AG_ID,STATION,EID,UNIT_STATUS,ATH_TRIP_NO(RECOVERY_CDTS,EID,NUM_1,UNID)) 
) 
PIVOT (MIN(CDTS) FOR (UNIT_STATUS) IN ('DP' DP,'ER' ER, 'AR' AR,'TR' TR,'TA' TA,'TP' TP,'PS' PS,'TG' TG,'AG' AG,'HB' HB,'TO' TO_LOC,'AO' AO,'TC' TC,'AC' AC,'AM' AM,'OS' OS)) ) t1
GROUP BY UNID,AG_ID,STATION,EID,NUM_1,DP,ER,AR,TR,TA,TP,PS,TG,AG,HB,TO_LOC,AO,TC,AC,AM,OS,TRIP_NO
ORDER BY EID,UNID,TRIP_NO
```

But the problem is that I need to use it as a view and cannot use this big query in my application. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you tag the dbms you're using, you'll probably get better attention... (Some non-ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: Considering the way the OP wrote the PIVOT clause it should be oracle, at least version 11g.

Answer (score 0):

If the used DBMS supports materialized views, you can use them so the result will be already calculated at the moment you are requesting the database. For example, in the Oracle-like DBMSs, you can use something like:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW VW_TEST 
REFRESH ON DEMAND
START WITH SYSDATE
NEXT SYSDATE + 1
AS
SELECT UNID AS UNIT_ID,AG_ID,STATION,EID,NUM_1 AS EVENT_NUMBER,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(DP,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS DP,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(ER,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS ER,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(AR,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS AR,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TR,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS TR,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TA,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS TA,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TP,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS TP,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(PS,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS PS,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TG,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS TG,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(AG,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS AG,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(HB,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS HB,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TO_LOC,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS TO_LOC,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(AO,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS AO,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TC,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS TC,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(AC,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS AC,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(AM,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS AM,
(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(OS,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) AS OS,
TRIP_NO
FROM (
SELECT * FROM (SELECT u.UNID, u.AG_ID, u.STATION ,u.EID, u.NUM_1, u.CDTS,u.UNIT_STATUS,ATH_TRIP_NO(u.RECOVERY_CDTS,u.EID,u.NUM_1,u.UNID) TRIP_NO 
FROM UN_HI u 
WHERE u.RECOVERY_CDTS IN(SELECT MAX(RECOVERY_CDTS) AS RECOVERY_CDTS FROM UN_HI GROUP BY UNID,AG_ID,STATION,EID,UNIT_STATUS,ATH_TRIP_NO(RECOVERY_CDTS,EID,NUM_1,UNID)) 
) 
PIVOT (MIN(CDTS) FOR (UNIT_STATUS) IN ('DP' DP,'ER' ER, 'AR' AR,'TR' TR,'TA' TA,'TP' TP,'PS' PS,'TG' TG,'AG' AG,'HB' HB,'TO' TO_LOC,'AO' AO,'TC' TC,'AC' AC,'AM' AM,'OS' OS)) ) t1
GROUP BY UNID,AG_ID,STATION,EID,NUM_1,DP,ER,AR,TR,TA,TP,PS,TG,AG,HB,TO_LOC,AO,TC,AC,AM,OS,TRIP_NO
ORDER BY EID,UNID,TRIP_NO
```

This will refresh your view once daily, you can adapt it for your need.

Answer (score 0):

As a first option I would try to see if rewriting the query in a way that allows the optimizer to push the conditions on EID to the most nested subquery could solve the problem. The following one, where EID is used in the semi-join evaluation (IN clause), should be good for that. I cannot warranty it's correct because I can't try it, but I'm quite confident about it. You should test it.

```
SELECT UNID AS UNIT_ID,AG_ID,STATION,EID,NUM_1 AS EVENT_NUMBER,
    DP, ER, AR, TR, TA, TP, PS, TG, AG, HB, TO_LOC, AO, TC, AC, AM, OS, 
    TRIP_NO
FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM (
                SELECT u.UNID, u.AG_ID, u.STATION ,u.EID, u.NUM_1,
                    (TO_DATE(SUBSTR(u.CDTS,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) as CDTS,
                    u.UNIT_STATUS,
                    ATH_TRIP_NO(u.RECOVERY_CDTS,u.EID,u.NUM_1,u.UNID) TRIP_NO 
                FROM UN_HI u
                WHERE (UNIT_STATUS) IN (
                        'DP','ER', 'AR','TR','TA','TP','PS','TG','AG','HB',
                        'TO_LOC','AO','TC','AC','AM','OS'
                    )
                    and (u.EID, u.RECOVERY_CDTS) IN(
                        SELECT u.EID,MAX(RECOVERY_CDTS) AS RECOVERY_CDTS 
                        FROM UN_HI 
                        GROUP BY u.EID,UNID,AG_ID,STATION,EID,UNIT_STATUS,ATH_TRIP_NO(RECOVERY_CDTS,EID,NUM_1,UNID)
                    )
            ) 
        PIVOT (
            MIN(CDTS) 
            FOR (UNIT_STATUS) IN (
                'DP' DP,'ER' ER, 'AR' AR,'TR' TR,'TA' TA,'TP' TP,'PS' PS,'TG' TG,'AG' AG,'HB' HB,
                'TO' TO_LOC,'AO' AO,'TC' TC,'AC' AC,'AM' AM,'OS' OS
            )
        )
    ) t1
GROUP BY UNID,AG_ID,STATION,EID,NUM_1,DP,ER,AR,TR,TA,TP,PS,TG,AG,HB,TO_LOC,AO,TC,AC,AM,OS,TRIP_NO
ORDER BY EID,UNID,TRIP_NO
```

Then I spot that you use the "self semi-join" to find MIN(CDTS) just among those ones sharing the highest value on RECOVERY_CDTS, that may be found in a simpler way using the [LAST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions083.htm#SQLRF00653) function, so you can try this other query that should be also faster than the previous one and than your original one.

```
SELECT UNID AS UNIT_ID,AG_ID,STATION,EID,NUM_1 AS EVENT_NUMBER,
    DP, ER, AR, TR, TA, TP, PS, TG, AG, HB, TO_LOC, AO, TC, AC, AM, OS, 
    TRIP_NO
FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM (
                SELECT u.UNID, u.AG_ID, u.STATION ,u.EID, u.NUM_1,
                    u.UNIT_STATUS,
                    ATH_TRIP_NO(u.RECOVERY_CDTS,u.EID,u.NUM_1,u.UNID) TRIP_NO,
                    min(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(u.CDTS,0,14),'YYYY/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS')+3/24) keep (dense_rank least order by RECOVERY_CDTS)as CDTS
                FROM UN_HI u
                where (UNIT_STATUS) IN (
                    'DP','ER', 'AR','TR','TA','TP','PS','TG','AG','HB',
                    'TO_LOC','AO','TC','AC','AM','OS'
                )
                GROUP BY UNID,AG_ID,STATION,EID,UNIT_STATUS,ATH_TRIP_NO(RECOVERY_CDTS,EID,NUM_1,UNID)
            ) 
        PIVOT (
            MIN(CDTS) 
            FOR (UNIT_STATUS) IN (
                'DP' DP,'ER' ER, 'AR' AR,'TR' TR,'TA' TA,'TP' TP,'PS' PS,'TG' TG,'AG' AG,'HB' HB,
                'TO' TO_LOC,'AO' AO,'TC' TC,'AC' AC,'AM' AM,'OS' OS
            )
        )
    ) t1
GROUP BY UNID,AG_ID,STATION,EID,NUM_1,DP,ER,AR,TR,TA,TP,PS,TG,AG,HB,TO_LOC,AO,TC,AC,AM,OS,TRIP_NO
ORDER BY EID,UNID,TRIP_NO
```